# Python, why I get different result between .py and shell when I use generator yield?

Tags: python, generator

I am learning coroutine, I have found a pdf named "A Curious Course On Coroutines and Concurrecy".
There is a flaky example:

```
def countdown(n):
print("Counting down from", n)
while n >= 0:
    newvalue = (yield n)
    # If a new value got sent in, reset n with it
    if newvalue is not None:
        n = newvalue
    else:
        n -= 1
```

I have put it in a file named "bogus.py", then i went to the python shell..

```
>>> from bogus import countdown
>>> c = countdown(5)
>>> for n in c:
...     print(n)
...     if n == 5:
...         c.send(3)
...
Counting down from 5
5
3
2
1
0
>>>
```

Yes, I got 5 3 2 1 0...
But when i put these statements into the bogus.py, I got the different result...

```
def countdown(n):
print("Counting down from", n)
while n >= 0:
    newvalue = (yield n)
    # If a new value got sent in, reset n with it
    if newvalue is not None:
        n = newvalue
    else:
        n -= 1

c = countdown(5)
for n in c:
    print(n)
    if n == 5:
        c.send(3)
```

then...

```
$ python bogus.py
Counting down from 5
5
2
1
0
```

I got 5 2 1 0...! Where is the 3?
I am so puzzled, and I really don't kwow why...
Please help me, and sorry for my english.

oh, I also found if I changed a little in shell code, then I got:

```
>>> from bogus import countdown
>>> c = countdown(5)
>>> for n in c:
...     print(n)
...     if n == 5:
...         k = c.send(3)
...
Counting down from 5
5
2
1
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

In interactive mode, Python auto-prints the `repr` of any expression statement that evaluates to something other than `None`. This excludes expression statements inside functions and classes, but it includes expression statements in loops, such as this one:

```
>>> for n in c:
...     print(n)
...     if n == 5:
...         c.send(3)  # <- right here
```

That's where the `3` comes from in interactive mode. Personally, I've never come across a situation where this behavior is desirable.